# Warning pop-up letting user know pre iOS 5 is not officially supported

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Does anyone know if adding a pop-up when a user launches an app that says that the app is optimized for iOS 5 (and suggests that the user upgrade if they are experiencing problems) is against Apple guidelines?

I have a story in my queue that is requesting me to add this feature to our app, but it seems like this could end up being something that Apple rejects the app update for.

Comment: Don't know for sure if it's explicitly against policy, but I wouldn't be surprised if they rejected it for that reason.

Comment: It would certainly be better to fix your app for older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the iOS Deployment Target in Target Build Settings to OS 5, and the app won't even load on devices running any older OS versions.  No warning needed.